# How to check if all the elements in an array are positive integers?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array, say

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 5, 11, 5 };
```

How can I check (in the most easy and efficient way) that all elements are positive? If at least one number is not a positive integer, the system will respond in a negative  way.

**Desired output:**

if all the numbers are positive, then it will display "All Positive" else "Wrong"

**My shot**

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 5, 11, 5 };
var x = array.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9');
if (x == true) "Positive" else "Wrong";
```

Comment: `array.All(x => x > -1)`?

Comment: Well you should check using `.Any` of them is less that zero

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You were nearly there before - but you were comparing with characters instead of integers.

If you want to check whether everything is strictly positive, use:

```
bool allPositive = array.All(x => x > 0);
```

If you actually want to check they're all non-negative (i.e. 0 is acceptable) use:

```
bool allNonNegative = array.All(x => x >= 0);
```

You should definitely consider what you want to do with 0, as your problem statement is actually contradictory. ("All positive" and "no negative" aren't the same thing.)

Note that just like [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx), [`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) will quit as soon as it knows the result - so if the first value is negative, it won't need to look through the rest.

Comment: Damn! My solution was faster `:D`

Answer (score 6):

Use [Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) like:

```
if(array.Any(r => r < 0))
{
     //Negative number found
}
else
{
   //All numbers are positive
}
```

Or you can use [Enumerable.All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) Like:

```
if(array.All(r => r > 0))
{
    //All numbers are positive 
}
else
{
   //Negative number found
}
```

Comment: Given that the OP expressed this as "all values are positive" I think it's clearer to use `All` and a positive test than `Any` with a negative test and the results reversed.

Comment: OP does mention `at least one negative number`, so `Any` would still be valid.

Comment: @VimalStan, `.Any` is valid, but Jon Skeet is saying that using `All` is more clear.

Comment: @VimalStan What JonSkeet wants to say is `All` is more relevant in the context of all positive numbers and yes `Any` is also valid

Answer (score 3):

You almost there. But in your condition, you comparing characters instead of integers which is wrong in your situation.

Use [`Enumerable.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) like;

> Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 5, 11, 5 };
bool allPositive = array.All(x => x > 0);
Console.WriteLine(allPositive);
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/B2veIP).

Remember `0` is not positive.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a C# solution to your problem (it should be rather efficient performance-wise):

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 5, 11,5 };

bool _allPositive=true;

for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
 if(array[i]<0 {_allPositive=false; break;}
}
```

`bool _allPositive` indicates the result (you can use string var if you prefer). Essentially, the same syntax can apply to Java-like languages, including scripting.

Answer (score 1):

```
string result = array.Any(x => x < 0)?"Wrong":"Positive";
```